# reading graph from file in C

Tags: c, input

I'm trying to read a graph from an input file (`./graph.o <in.txt`), and while I've done this before with similar code, I'm now getting strange errors and don't understand what's causing this behavior.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **allocateMemory(int rows, int cols) {
  char **array = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(char));
  }
  return array;
}

void readGraph(char **graph, int rows, int cols) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      graph[i][j] = getchar();
    }
    getchar(); //newline character
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int rows,cols;
  scanf("%d %d\n", &rows, &cols); 
  printf("rows:%d, cols:%d\n", rows, cols); 

  char **graph = allocateMemory(rows,cols);
  readGraph(graph,rows,cols); 
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
      printf("%d:%c ", j, graph[i][j]);
    }
  } 
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The input file has the following simplified form:

```
3 5
#####
#   #
#####
```

The output I get is:

```
rows:3, cols:5
0:# 1:# 2:# 3:# 4:# 0:
 1:# 2:  3:  4:  0:
 2:# 3:# 4:#
```

Clearly the newline character is not processed the way it should be, even though there's an extra getchar() to account for it and the input file has no additional white space.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. Have you looked in e.g. a hex-editor to see that the input file doesn't contain any unprintable characters? There's no spaces between the last `#` on each line and the newline? Did you copy it from a Windows system to a POSIX system (e.g. Linux)? If you edited it on e.g. a Linux system, what kind of newlines do the editor save (Windows or POSIX)?

Comment: Hint: use braces even if they seem redundant :)

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `.o` suffix is usually used for *object* file, not executable programs. Object files are used as input to the linker to create the executable file.

Comment: Are you getting `'\n'` **and** `'\r'` from the input?

Comment: Use a debugger and/or print the raw values returned from `getchar`

Comment: @Jabberwocky If I try an online debugger, it works fine. Printing the raw values doesn't give new insights.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Even if I make a new file and manually type the input on my linux system, I still get the wrong output. And there are no extra spaces.

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/uABZK9

Comment: Ad a general guideline: if input is line-based (IOW newlines matter), read lines and parse them. Do not parse the input directly.

Comment: Print every character you read, even the "newline". Print it as both a character and its encoded integer value. That should tell you exactly what is actually read from the file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I get this when I print out the encoded integer values, it seems getchar() reads extra carriage returns (13) and not only newline characters (10):
35 35 35 35 35 13
10 35 32 32 32 35
13 10 35 35 35 35

Comment: Well then I'd say it's a problem with the editor you're using to edit the input file. What editor are you using? What are its settings?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using Visual Studio Code

Comment: [This tutorial](https://qvault.io/clean-code/line-breaks-vs-code-lf-vs-crlf/) about the CR/LF versus LF issue could be helpful to read.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This solved it. Thank you so much.